# Can a Cisco switch be a DHCP client and server at the same time?

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I have currently the following situation:

ISP-Router --> Own NetGear Router (in DMZ of ISP-router) --> 28p Cisco Switch --> devices and AP

The ISP-Router only hands out 4 IP-addresses. I have more than 4 devices, so I added an aditional router to hand out more IP-Addresses. So my ISP thinks that I use 2 IP-addresses: 1 for the Netgear Router, 1 for my Harddisk recorder that needs to have an IP from the ISP. (Telenet in case you are wondering).

What I want to know, is that if it is possible that I can connect my Cisco Switch to my ISP-router directly without leasing more than 4 IP-addresses.

ISP-Router --> 28p Cisco Switch --> Devices and AP

Is it possible to accomplish this with VLANs? For example VLAN1 gets IP-addresses from the ISP-Router, VLAN2 is my home network where the Cisco switch hands out IP-addresses to my devices. Offcourse, all my devices should be able to connect to the internet (which is managed by the ISP-router). I would like to have my home network to have it's own address range (different than the ISP range).

Hopefully an easy question for you guys. I'm just learning here :-).
If you need more info, please ask.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I too often find incomprehensible downvotes, always without an explanation. I too take it upon myself to redress the situation.

Comment: Your hardware would need multiple physical LAN ports.  Once you have hardware with multiple LAN ports, you can setup VLANS at that point, just like if you had multiple routers going to your switch.

Comment: What do you mean with hardware? All my devices?

Answer (score 1):

A switch does not need an IP address, unless it is managed. I am not sure I have identified correctly your switch but, if it is [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041ORNC4), then **it is managed**, and it will need one IP address from your ISP router.

The machines attached to the switch do not need an IP address in order to talk **to the switch**, but they will ask one to talk to the internet to the ISP router. Your faithful switch will pass along their requests to the router, which will quickly exhaust its really tiny pool of IP addresses, and you will be in trouble.

Your first configuration made much more sense, and allowed a very large number (up to 253) of clients to the DHCP server on the Netgear Router.

As for VLANs, even if they were allowed by the ISP router, each with four maximum clients, it would still amount to a total of 16 clients (much less than the 253 mentioned above), which would also have trouble talking to each other.

Comment: I have the SG500-28p. 

My actual goal is to create a vlan of 4 ports (DHCP with ip-addresses from the ISP) and a VLAN of 20 ports using the DHCP server of the switch itself and in another range than the range of the ISP.

Comment: So for example:

VLAN1: Network 192.168.0.0 with 4 IP Addresses max 

VLAN2: Network 172.10.30.0 with x IP Addresses 

But the devices connected to VLAN2 should be able to connect to the internet.

Comment: @TonyVerbert Yes, that's fine. But remember that 1 of the four addresses in 192.168.0.0/24 is the switch itself: like I said, a managed switch requires an IP address.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. It will be a DHCP client from the ISP. 

Now one security question about the new situation: Is the Cisco Switch 'safe' enough to be in the DMZ of the ISP-Router?

Comment: @TonyVerbert What is *safe enough*? All I can tell you is that there is no known exploit affecting it as of now, I just checked.

Comment: I just did a test (that failed). 
VLAN1 is the default VLAN (is going to be my home network)
I Created a VLAN2 and assiged two ports to that VLAN.
I enabled the DHCP server of my Cisco Switch. 
My PC is in range with the scope of the DHCP server.  (assigned address in range of the address of the DHCP server.
When I connect my internet connection in one of the 2 ports of VLAN2, I however cannot connect to the internet with my PC.

Is this normal? Are there settings to check?

Comment: @TonyVerbert Pls check this, http://superuser.com/questions/667631/network-is-unreachable-when-attempting-to-ping-google-but-internal-addresses/667800#667800